# html buttons calling python functions using bottle

Tags: python, html, boto, bottle

I'm currently trying to right a python script that overnight turns off all of our EC2 instances then in the morning my QA team can go to a webpage and press a button to turn the instances back on.

I have written my python script that turns the severs off using boto.  I also have a function which when ran turns them back on.

I have an html doc with buttons on it.

I'm just struggling to work out how to get these buttons to call the function.  I'm using bottle rather than flask and I have no Java SCript experience.  So I would like t avoid Ajax if possible.  I dont mind if the whole page has to reload after the button is pressed.  After the single press the webpage isnt needed anyway.

Comment: Look into `AJAX` requests, each button would call an end-point that will switch on the adjacent server (passed as a query parameter or `post`)

Answer (score 3):

What I have ended up doing to fix this issue is used bottle to make a url which completes the needed function.  Then just made an html button that links to the relevant url.